# no scrollbar for empty big width div on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

using this code on chrome browsers will give me a div with a horizontal scrollbar

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll;background:black;width:300px;height:100px;">
  <div style="min-width: 1000px;"></div>
</div>
```

but not on firefox,
on ff it will only have a scrollbar if the internal div has some content,

I'm wondering if this is a known issue, and if there's any workaround for it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the inner div some height it will work in Firefox. I've added a border on the right so you can see it is actually scrolling. You're right though that does appear to be a browser quirk.

Note that `overflow-y` is for vertical scrolling (y axis) and `overflow-x` is for horizontal scrolling (x axis).

```html
<div style="overflow-x: scroll;background:black;width:300px;height:100px;">
  <div style="min-width: 1000px;border-right:20px solid red;height:100%;"></div>
</div>
```